# How to check http status code in vuejs and return value

Tags: vue.js, getelementbyid, http-status-codes, availability

I need to check the status code in vuejs, whether is it 200 or else. Here is my code, but i have errors.

```
methods:{
  userSearch(){
    let searchUrl = dataUrl+this.usersearch;
            
                fetch(searchUrl).then(statusCode => {
                    if(statusCode == 200){
                        message = "Not Available"
                        $("#availability").innerHTML = message
                    }
                    else {
                        message = "Available"
                        $("#availability").innerHTML = message
            }})
```

this should return in my p element with id="availability" whether the user is available or not, depending on the status code. I am calling this method in the input field on enter.

Comment: `fetch` resolves to a [`Response` object](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), not just a status code…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deceze pointed out, the `fetch` function resolves to a Response Object.

You can see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#handling-client-and-server-errors) how to properly handle the HTTP status of the response.

But, for your code, it should be something like this:

```
userSearch() {
    let searchUrl = dataUrl+this.usersearch;          
    fetch(searchUrl).then(response => {
        if(response.status == 200){
            message = "Not Available"
            $("#availability").innerHTML = message
        }
        else {
            message = "Available"
            $("#availability").innerHTML = message
        }
    })
}
```

As just part of the code was provided, there might be other causes for the error, that I cannot see with just this snippet.